# In Windows Phone 8.1, Is it possible to read mac address of device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1, Is it possible to read mac address of device.
I want to build a app which search the all available network and connect to the preconfigured(in app) network.
and also turn on the WiFi using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone OS does not give access to programmatically join networks, this has to be an action initiated by the end user, it is possible however to [enumerate the current network connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700381.aspx) whic does allow some information about the adaptor, but apparently not the physical (MAC) address...